# How to pass detail url inside the list in DRF

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Here i am trying to pass the `detail` url inside the `list`.How can i do it ?

serialzers.py

```
class CategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    detail_url = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = '__all__'

    def get_detail_url(self,obj):
        return "/category/detail/{}/".format(obj.pk)
```

views.py

```
class CategoryListAPIView(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Category.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CategorySerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAdminUser]

class CategoryDetailAPIView(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = Category.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CategorySerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAdminUser]
```

with the **`list`** url it displays the data like this

```
HTTP 200 OK
Allow: GET, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept

{
    "count": 3,
    "next": null,
    "previous": null,
    "results": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "category1",
            "description": "description",
        
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "category2",
            "description": "description"
```

But the result i want is :

```
HTTP 200 OK
Allow: GET, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept

{
    "count": 3,
    "next": null,
    "previous": null,
    "results": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "category1",
            "description": "description",
             Detail Link of Category1

         
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "category2",
            "description": "description",
              Detail Link of Category2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify your serializer class to provide the detail url. For this you need to define a **serializer method field** in your serializer that returns the url as :

```
class CategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    detail_url = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    
    class Meta:
        model = Your_model
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'description', 'detail_url')
   
    def get_detail_url(self, obj):
        return "{}/category/detail/{}/".format(BASE_URL(e.g., "http://localhost:8000"), obj.id)
```

In case you want to make your base_url dynamic for different servers, I recommend you to create a local_settings.py([local settings demo](https://techstream.org/Bits/Local-Settings-in-django)) file where you can define a constant **BASE_URL** as:

```
BASE_URL = 'http://localhost:8000' # or any domain name you want
```

and use it as:

```
# import as 
from django.conf import settings
# use it as 
return "{}/category/detail/{}/".format(settings.BASE_URL, obj.id)
```

Comment: *Got nothing*? Are you getting empty result or the detail url is not being shown?

Comment: You need to include your base_url(example: http://localhost:8000) as i have defined so that it can be treated as a link.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use SerializerMethodField field to return custom data or string for each object or record.

```
class CategoryListAPIView(serializers.ModelSerializer):
detail = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

class Meta:
    model = User

def get_detail(self, obj):
    # generate your return url here. you can get object id by obj.id
    return obj.id
```